# How to run a javascript when browser process is killed?

Tags: javascript, browser, process, termination

I hav onUnload="cleanup()" defined in my html body tag.
The cleanup() method in javascript is

function cleanup()
        {--clean up session--}.

But when the browser is terminated by killing the process using task manager, I want to do the same action as cleanup. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. If the process is forcefully killed, nobody cares about your scripts.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way of calling the session cleanup function in server when this happens?

Comment: That depends on what your "session cleanup function" does. If it is client-side code: no. If it is an Ajax-y request to a server script that performs some function: yes, depending on your session management. Look at a Cron job that performs the clean-up for sessions that have timed out.